# How to process this in parallel on cluster using MapFunction and ReduceFunction of spark-java api?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java8.

Have to do a calculation using group by on various conditions using **java api i.e. using MapFunction and ReduceFunction.**

**Scenario :**

Have source data given sample as below

```
+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------+
| country|generated_date|industry_id|industry_name|  revenue| state|
+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------+
|Country1|    2020-03-01|    Indus_1| Indus_1_Name| 12789979|State1|
|Country1|    2019-06-01|    Indus_1| Indus_1_Name| 56189008|State1|
|Country1|    2019-03-01|    Indus_1| Indus_1_Name| 12789979|State1|
|Country1|    2020-03-01|    Indus_2| Indus_2_Name| 21789933|State2|
|Country1|    2018-03-01|    Indus_2| Indus_2_Name|300789933|State2|
|Country1|    2019-03-01|    Indus_3| Indus_3_Name| 27989978|State3|
|Country1|    2017-06-01|    Indus_3| Indus_3_Name| 56189008|State3|
|Country1|    2017-03-01|    Indus_3| Indus_3_Name| 30014633|State3|
|Country2|    2020-03-01|    Indus_4| Indus_4_Name| 41789978|State1|
|Country2|    2018-03-01|    Indus_4| Indus_4_Name| 56189008|State1|
|Country3|    2019-03-01|    Indus_5| Indus_5_Name| 37899790|State3|
|Country3|    2018-03-01|    Indus_5| Indus_5_Name| 56189008|State3|
|Country3|    2017-03-01|    Indus_5| Indus_5_Name| 67789978|State3|
|Country1|    2020-03-01|    Indus_6| Indus_6_Name| 12789979|State1|
|Country1|    2020-06-01|    Indus_6| Indus_6_Name| 37899790|State1|
|Country1|    2018-03-01|    Indus_6| Indus_6_Name| 56189008|State1|
|Country3|    2020-03-01|    Indus_7| Indus_7_Name| 26689900|State1|
|Country3|    2020-12-01|    Indus_7| Indus_7_Name|212359979|State1|
|Country3|    2019-03-01|    Indus_7| Indus_7_Name| 12789979|State1|
|Country1|    2018-03-01|    Indus_8| Indus_8_Name|212359979|State2|
+--------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------+
```

**Need to calculate various calculation like avg(revenue) for each given group 
for given dates , able to do it but not at all scaling in spark-cluster.**

For the same I am doing below thing but this is not at all scaling...hence understood I need to use 
MapFunction and ReduceFunction of java.. not sure how to do it ?

```
//Will get dates to for which I need to calculate , this provided by external source 
        List<String> datesToCalculate = Arrays.asList("2019-03-01","2020-06-01","2018-09-01");

        //Will get groups  to calculate , this provided by external source ..will keep changing
        //Have around 100s of groups.
        List<String> groupsToCalculate = Arrays.asList("Country","Country-State");

        //For each data given need to calculate avg(revenue) for each given group 
        //for those given each date of datesToCalculate for those records whose are later than given date.
        //i.e. 

        //Now I am doing some thing like this..but it is not scaling

        datesToCalculate.stream().forEach( cal_date -> {

            Dataset<IndustryRevenue> calc_ds = ds.where(col("generated_date").gt(lit(cal_date)));

            //this keep changing for each cal_date
            Dataset<Row> final_ds = calc_ds
                                      .withColumn("calc_date", to_date(lit(cal_date)).cast(DataTypes.DateType));

            //for each group it calcuate separate set
            groupsToCalculate.stream().forEach( group -> {

                String tempViewName = new String("view_" + cal_date + "_" + group);

                final_ds.createOrReplaceTempView(tempViewName);

                String query = "select "  
                                  + " avg(revenue) as mean, "
                                  + "from " + tempViewName                      
                                  + " group by " + group;

                System.out.println("query : " + query);
                Dataset<Row> resultDs  = spark.sql(query);

                Dataset<Row> finalResultDs  =  resultDs
                                 .withColumn("calc_date", to_date(lit(cal_date)).cast(DataTypes.DateType))
                                 .withColumn("group", to_date(lit(group)).cast(DataTypes.DateType));


                //Writing to each group for each date is taking hell lot of time.
                // For each record it is save at a time
                // want to move out unioning all finalResultDs and write in batches
                finalResultDs
                   .write().format("parquet")
                   .mode("append")
                   .save("/tmp/"+ tempViewName);

                spark.catalog().dropTempView(tempViewName);

            });

        });
```

Due to for-loops it is taking more than 20hrs for processing few million records.
so how to avoid forloops and make it run it quickly.

Here is the sample code

https://github.com/BdLearnerr/Java-mapReduce/blob/master/MapReduceScalingProblem.java

**Expected output :**

```
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| group-name   |   group-value  |         mean |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
|country-state |Country1-State1 | 2.53448845E7 |
|country-state |Country3-State3 |   6.7789978E7|
|country-state |Country1-State2 | 1.919319606E8|
|country-state |Country4-State1 |    9.789979E7|
|country-state |Country1-State3 |   2.9339748E7|
|country-state |Country3-State1 |     2.66899E7|
|country-state |Country2-State1 |   4.1789978E7|
|country       |Country4        |    9.789979E7|
|country       |Country1        |   8.5696311E7|
|country       |Country3        |   4.7239939E7|
|country       |Country2        |   4.1789978E7|
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: why 3 questions with the same issue? And what means not scaling? I mean, right now you have two nested for loops and inside you're doing some Spark stuff.

Comment: also you should cache `final_ds` if you're reusing it in the inner loop - and afterwards uncache

Comment: i doubt very much that a foreach is the way to go

Comment: My advice: 1) use scala or pysaprk, not java. Use dataframe grouping by, etc. no need for for loops. look back at the docs as this seems quite problematic asking the same question more than once. U must understand the basics. for, foreach is driver stuff that may or may not launch distributed processing. Read this link, just take a step back: https://data-flair.training/blogs/spark-tutorial/

Comment: show the expected output pls

Comment: I do not do java, only scala.

Comment: will do after dinner

Comment: do you really need to create different files for every date? At the moment you are saving N x M times(N dates size, M groups size). I would suggest to use union to save the intermediate results into the `finalDS` and then just save the results of the `finalDS`

Comment: To replace the current version with one only save: 1. move the definition of `finalResultDs` out of the loops 2. replace `finalResultDs.write().format("parquet")...` with `finalResultDs = finalResultDs.union(resultDs)` this will append all the result into finalResultDs 3. just after the 2nd loop do `finalResultDs.persist()` 4. finally execute `finalResultDs.write().format("parquet")...`

Comment: yes it is immutable although the transformation return a reference to the resulting dataframe i.e: `var finalResultDs = empy_df` then inside the 2nd loop you do `finalResultDs = finalResultDs.union(resultDs)` instead of saving.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is part of the solution addressing your immediate questions, but I leave aspects for you to fill in as well. There are other approaches, but this is my quick take from what I understand. Success. No foreach req'd. I might have got the wrong take on what you need. Excuses if that is the case. You may want to think about .cache in this approach.

```
// Assuming constant names in terms of country names are spelled similarly and consistently
// Not clear if by date or for selected dates. If selected dates then use another list 
// This approach will scale due to JOIN and AGG and no foreach, etc.
// Spark will fuse the code together if it can, but there are shuffles

// This is for Country, State. You can apply the approach to just Country and then UNION the 2 DF's with common names and definitions. Try it out
// NB: You make a custom grouping by concatenating the Country & State or you can leave as is, and for 2nd query you can just fill in country and put a blank value into the State.
// I leave that up to you.

import spark.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dfC = Seq(("USA", "Ohio"), ("NZ", "Otago")).toDF("sCountry", "sState") // Your search criteria at Country / State level, cannot so simple .isin - why?

val d = List("23-10-2001", "12-12-2003") // or Array

val dfS = Seq(
             ("USA", "Ohio", "23-10-2001", 2),
             ("USA", "Ohio", "23-10-2001", 2),
             ("USA", "Ohio", "23-10-2011", 2),
             ("USA", "Texas", "23-10-2001", 2),
             ("USA", "Virgina", "23-10-2001", 10),
             ("USA", "Virgina", "23-10-2001", 6),
             ("USA", "vanDiemensLand", "23-10-2001", 26),
             ("NL", "vanDiemensLand", "23-10-2001", 16),
             ("UK", "Middlesex", "23-10-2001", 3)
             ).toDF("country", "state", "date", "some_val") 
dfS.show(false)

// 1. For Country & State 
// JOIN acts as a filter as is inner join and alleviates the .isin for multiple cols i.e. Country||State
val df1 = dfS.join(dfC, (dfS("country") === dfC("sCountry")) && (dfS("state") === dfC("sState"))).drop("sCountry").drop("sState")
df1.show(false)

val df2 = df1.filter($"date".isin(d:_*)).groupBy("country", "state").avg("some_val") 
df2.show(false)

// 2. For Country only
... to fill in by you
...

// 3. UNION df2 & df3
...

// 4. Save with partitioning.
```

Comment: How did u go here?

Comment: hi ,how r u doing ? can you advice on this use-case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524489/can-this-use-case-be-done-by-lag-any-other-function-of-spark-if-so-how-can-this