# Can this use-case be done by lag/any-other function of Spark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-2.4.1v. I have a use-case in my project where, for each date (process_date) I need to consider that day record with previous day record, and do certain other operations on that data-set.
So how can prepare data-set for this? I tried with lag function but not got much success.

For the above use-case, given data as below:

```
+----------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+
|company_id|  gen_date|year|quarter|total_assets|create_date|
+----------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+
| 989856662|2019-01-02|2019|      1| 3900.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|2019-01-02|2019|      1| 4836.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|2019-01-02|2019|      1| 5836.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 3800.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 3834.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 5834.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 3700.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 3900.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 5833.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 3832.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 3700.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 5832.435058| 2019-09-11|
+----------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+
```

Here gen_date is the key column. For each gen_date, I need to take its previous available gen_date record. These will be processed together as set i.e. for process_date 2019-01-02 -- it should have records of 2019-01-02 & 2019-01-01 like wise for process_date records of gen_date 2018-12-30 & its previous gen_date i.e. 2018-12-29, but here in 2018-12-29 gen_date records are not available hence should be considered gen_date 2018-12-30  records.

**In the given set:**

For process_date 2019-01-02 => records of ( gen_date 2019-01-02 ) +  records of ( gen_date  2019-01-01)
For process_date 2019-01-01 => records of ( gen_date 2019-01-01 ) +  records of ( gen_date  2018-12-31)
For process_date 2018-12-31 => records of ( gen_date 2018-12-31 ) +  records of ( gen_date  2018-12-30)
For process_date 2018-12-30 => records of ( gen_date 2018-12-30 ) +  no previous gen_date records.

**The out put should be as below:**

```
+----------+------------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+
|company_id|process_date|  gen_date|year|quarter|total_assets|create_date|
+----------+------------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+
| 989856662|  2019-01-02|2019-01-02|2019|      1| 3900.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|  2019-01-02|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 3800.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|  2019-01-02|2019-01-02|2019|      1| 4836.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|  2019-01-02|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 3834.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|  2019-01-02|2019-01-02|2019|      1| 5836.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|  2019-01-02|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 5834.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|  2019-01-01|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 3800.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|  2019-01-01|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 3700.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|  2019-01-01|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 3834.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|  2019-01-01|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 3900.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|  2019-01-01|2019-01-01|2019|      1| 5834.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|  2019-01-01|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 5833.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|  2018-12-31|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 3700.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|  2018-12-31|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 3832.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|  2018-12-31|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 3900.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|  2018-12-31|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 3700.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|  2018-12-31|2018-12-31|2018|      4| 5833.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|  2018-12-31|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 5832.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856662|  2018-12-30|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 3832.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856665|  2018-12-30|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 3700.435058| 2019-09-11|
| 989856667|  2018-12-30|2018-12-30|2018|      4| 5832.435058| 2019-09-11|
+----------+------------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+
```

How to achieve above output ?

Below is the attached notebook url for the same.

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1165111237342523/988191344931748/7035720262824085/latest.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the previous day details for the given `gen_date` and the `company_id`, you can use the lag function as with the following `spec`,

```
val windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("company_id").orderBy("gen_date") 

val intermediateDF = finDF
  .withColumn("previous_gen_date", lag("gen_date",1).over(windowSpec))
```

The above step will get you the previous generation date based on the company_id and the gen_date and you can join this data with your original data to get the relevant previous day data.

```
val finalDF = intermediateDF.alias("a")
  .join(finDF.alias("b"), col("a.company_id") === col("b.company_id") &&
    col("a.previous_gen_date") === col("b.gen_date"), "left_outer")
    .select(col("a.*"),
      col("b.year").as("previous_gen_date_year"),
      col("b.quarter").as("previous_gen_date_quarter"),
      col("b.total_assets").as("previous_gen_date_total_assets"),
      col("b.create_date").as("previous_gen_date_create_date")
    )
```

The above join will yield the complete data for the previous day along with generate date.

```
+----------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|company_id|gen_date  |year|quarter|total_assets|create_date|previous_gen_date|previous_gen_date_year|previous_gen_date_quarter|previous_gen_date_total_assets|previous_gen_date_create_date|
+----------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|989856662 |2018-12-30|2018|4      |3832.435058 |2019-09-11 |null             |null                  |null                     |null                          |null                         |
|989856662 |2018-12-31|2018|4      |3700.435058 |2019-09-11 |2018-12-30       |2018                  |4                        |3832.435058                   |2019-09-11                   |
|989856662 |2019-01-01|2019|1      |3800.435058 |2019-09-11 |2018-12-31       |2018                  |4                        |3700.435058                   |2019-09-11                   |
|989856662 |2019-01-02|2019|1      |3900.435058 |2019-09-11 |2019-01-01       |2019                  |1                        |3800.435058                   |2019-09-11                   |
+----------+----------+----+-------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Here your `gen_date` can also act as `process_date` column, with this you compare the two days worth of data for any operation.

Comment: thanks Shiva , not sure if you understood my requirement correctly. for each record  for each day i.e. nothing but process_date , we should have two two records i.e. that day record + previous day record.... hence approximate output should contain 2x records.  I hope you got the requirement else let me know.